# Regarding screen lock and unlock

Tags: android

I am doing one application to lock and unlock a screen. I am using disableKeygaurd and reeanbleKeygaurd to lock and unlock. the below code i used to unlock:

```
if(mKeyguardLock ==  null){
  mKeyGuardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
  mKeyguardLock = mKeyGuardManager.newKeyguardLock("****");
  mKeyguardLock.disableKeyguard();  
}
```

and for lock:

```
if(mKeyguardLock != null){
 mKeyguardLock.reenableKeyguard();
 mKeyguardLock = null;
}
```

It is working fine. but problem is when user unexpectedly unlock a screen by dragging keygaurd(without using my app) then my app will not lock the screen for next time.. I want to work my application when user used unlock by dragging keygaurd also. what should I have to do this? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: I got solution for this question..

Comment: Would you mind posting that solution so the rest of us could see?

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This:

private KeyguardManager mKeyguardManager;
private KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock mKeyguardLock;
private static final String TAG = "ALERTLock";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     int flags = getFlagsForVersion();        
        getWindow().addFlags(flags);
        mKeyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);   
}

 private int getFlagsForVersion() {
        final String possibleFlags[] = new String[] {
            "FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED",
            "FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD",
            "FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON"
        };

        int flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
        for(String flag:possibleFlags) {
            try {
                Field field = WindowManager.LayoutParams.class.getField(flag);
                int value = field.getInt(null);
                flags |= value;
            }
            catch(NoSuchFieldException e) { }
            catch(IllegalAccessException e) { }
        }

        return flags;
    }

    private synchronized void enableKeyguard() {
        if (mKeyguardLock != null) {
            mKeyguardLock.reenableKeyguard();
            mKeyguardLock = null;
        }
    }

    private synchronized void disableKeyguard() {
        if (mKeyguardLock == null) {
            mKeyguardLock = mKeyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(TAG);
            mKeyguardLock.disableKeyguard();
        }
    }    
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        disableKeyguard();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        disableKeyguard();
    }
```

Comment: where should I call enableKeyguard() ..?

Comment: you can use it where you want enable keyguard for example @Override
 protected void onDestroy() {
     super.onDestroy();
     enableKeyguard(); }

Comment: @Manish: my problem is when user unexpectedly unlocks a screen by dragging keygaurd my app  will not lock next time...